# Proper image display

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So, I am making my own responsive website.
My question is - how can I set image width properly?

Image has to be set with min-width and width 100%. I was trying to mix them like that

```
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
```

But it didn't work. So i used this code instead

```
    max-width: 100em;
    min-width: 100em;
```

It works fine, even on my website. I added some content recently, and there was a problem with scroll bar (there wasn't scroll bar before, lack of content). Image was set to display at 100em, but scroll bar took some space, so to see whole image i had to scroll page to the right. I solved the problem using this code, but i don't know if it's correct solution.

```
    max-width: 98.96em;
    min-width: 98.9em;
```

If there is any "less mechanical" solution, then please tell me about it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't mean `em` , but `vw` - `100vw` is the full viewport width. `em` is a relative measurement unit derived from the current font size of the element.